# How to play mp3 from a url on windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, mp3, directshow

I am looking for a way to play an mp3 file from a url on Windows Mobile 5.

The examples I've found using the wmplib.WindowsMediaPlayer.url property work for a file on the device but don't seem to work for a http: url. The function seems to succeed without throwing an exception but no audio is played. I have tried the player.settings.volume = 100 and also calling player.controls.play. This method works for a Windows desktop application but not on the mobile device.

The other option, using DirectShow, is not simple as - according to various web sites I've looked at - Windows Mobile does not contain an Mpeg1 (or mp3) splitter / parser filter. I have found source code for two sample filters but cannot sucessfully compile either for Windows Mobile.

Does anyone know of a pre-compiled, preferrably free, mp3 parser / splitter filter for Windows Mobile or of a clear set of instructions for setting up a Visual Studio project to be able to compile one of the samples from source?

Comment: I also need this question answered.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this question. *bump*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Windows Media Player Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb248593(VS.85).aspx). Should be no problem for the Windows Windows Media Player to read multimedia streams from an URL.

Comment: That is what the WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer is.  I've tried unsuccessfully with the same results as the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/PocketStreamer.aspx)'s a project that creates an application for streaming music over a network connection to a Windows Mobile device. Maybe that code can help you.

Comment: This project is over 5 years old and it's "annoying side effects" that the author lists are unacceptable for my needs.  I was hoping with the later versions of the .NET Compact Framework (post version 1.1) would have the ability to stream music built in.